# Find groups of contiguous cells in a 3D binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, 3d, matrix

I want to find groups of contiguous cells in a matrix.

So for example let’s consider a 2D matrix below.

[image: 2d binary matrix]

In the given matrix there are 2 contiguous groups of cells with value `1`:

[image: contiguous 1s in binary matrix]

Here is one way to find these groups:

1. Assign 1st cell with value 1 a different value: let’s say `A`. Then examine cells with value `1` which are adjacent to `A` and set the value in those cells as `A`. Search this way until no more contiguous cells are found.
2. In the next step increment `A` to `B` and start with a cell having value `1`. Then follow the same steps as above.

This is kind of brute force and it won’t be efficient in 3D. Does anyone know of any algorithm that I could use with a little tweaking?

Or any easy solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some psuedo code for a simple flood fill algorithm:

```
>>> def flood(i, j, matrix):
...     if 0 <= i < len(matrix) and 0 <= j < len(matrix):
...         if matrix[i][j] == 1:
...             matrix[i][j] = 0
...             for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
...                 flood(i + dx, j + dy, matrix)

>>> count = 0
>>> while True:
...     i, j = get_one(matrix)
...     if i and j: #found a one
...         count += 1
...         flood(i, j, matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Robert. Kind of ended up using the flood fill algorithm for 3D.

Comment: As of now, I implemented Flood Fill and it is doing what I need to do. So will tick this as answer. Thanks.

Comment: amazing, can you please explain your algorithm and approach with complexity of it. I'm asking this for learning. Thank you.

Comment: search for "depth first search" "breadth first search" "flood fill" and "union find", or try this:
https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/
All should be O(V+E) = O(NM+4NM) = O(NM)
best approach is to iterate through cells of the matrix, if cell hasn't been found before, do a DFS.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do goes, often, under the label [connected component labelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). I won't elaborate further, the Wikipedia article explains matters better than I could or would.

But while I'm answering ...

You, and many others on SO, seem to think that simple iteration over all the elements of an array, which you characterise by the derogatory term *brute-force*, is something to be avoided at all costs.  Modern computers are very, very fast. Accessing each element of an array in order is something that most compilers can optimise the hell out of.

You seem to have fallen into the trap of thinking that accessing every element of a 3D array has time-complexity in `O(n^3)`, where `n` is the number of elements along each dimension of the array.  It isn't: accessing elements of an array is in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

Even if the time complexity of visiting each element in the array were in `O(n^3)` many sophisticated algorithms which offer better asymptotic time complexity, will prove, in practice, to deliver worse performance than the simpler algorithm.  Many sophisticated algorithms make it much harder for the compiler to optimise code.  And, bear in mind, that `O(n^2)` is an equivalence class of algorithms which includes algorithms with true time complexities such as `O(m+k*n^2)` where both of `m` and `k` are constants

Comment: Um, for connected component labelling, the sophisticated algorithm with optimal time complexity (i.e., use a disjoint set datastructure to get `O(input_size * inverseAckermann(input_size))` performance) can be made extremely fast and is the practical method of choice.

Comment: That said, I agree that it is silly to complain here about the "brute force" of needing to read your entire input.  If the question just wanted to find one connected component, it would have already answered itself.  But if the goal is to find *all* connected components, you need to look at the entire input anyway...

Comment: Thanks guys. Yea, you are right, I didn't want to use brute-force in derogatory means.. was just trying to explore if there are any other ways. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the same like finding [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in a graph, but with the whole thing extended to 3 dimensions. So you can use any of the linear time algorithms for 2D graphs and adapt the DFS also for the 3rd dimension. This should be straight forward.

As those algorithms are linear time you can't get better in terms of running time complexity.

Comment: yea. Did had a look at Strongly connected component. Did help clear few things. Appreciate that.